# Is there any way to improve the GROUP BY performance on this?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple problem, or at least the symptom of the problem is simple. The following query is lightning-fast without the `GROUP BY` (0.15 seconds) but super slow with the `GROUP BY` (over 100 seconds). Is there any way to improve this situation?

```
  SELECT a.id, SUM(t.amount)
    FROM account_transaction t
    JOIN transaction_code tc ON t.transaction_code_id = tc.id
    JOIN account a ON t.account_number = a.account_number
    JOIN account_northway_product anp ON anp.account_id = a.id
    JOIN northway_product np ON np.id = anp.northway_product_id
   WHERE 1
     AND np.code != 'O1'
     AND tc.code IN (0, 20, 40)
GROUP BY a.id
```

**Edit:** When I do an `EXPLAIN` on the `GROUP BY` version of the query, everything looks good except one row:

```
select_type: simple
table: tc
type: index
possible_keys: PRIMARY,code,code_2
key: code
key_len: 257
ref: NULL
rows: 30
Extra: Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

From what little I understand about `EXPLAIN`, `key_len` is bad because it's long. The "Using temporary; Using filesort;" is also bad. One thing I could do, I suppose, is reduce the length of `transaction_code.code` since I probably won't ever need more than 3 characters there. I don't know what to do about "Using temporary; Usingfilesort;" though.

Comment: Is there an index on a.id? If not, that would certainly help.

Comment: Yes, there is an index on `a.id`.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question but rather a possible workaround (that you have likely already considered).  It seems that you could run the query without the GROUP BY and put the results in a temporary table, and then run a GROUP BY on that temporary table.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly(?) the query planner might take these out, but it looks like you have tables you don't need in your query. Also rearranged the joins so account is listed first.

```
SELECT a.id,
       SUM(t.amount)
  FROM 
    account a
        INNER JOIN account_northway_product anp ON anp.account_id = a.id 
            INNER JOIN northway_product np ON np.id = anp.northway_product_id
        INNER JOIN account_transaction t ON t.account_number = a.account_number         
            INNER JOIN transaction_code tc ON t.transaction_code_id = tc.id
 WHERE 
   np.code != 'O1'
   AND tc.code IN (0, 20, 40)
 GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: You're totally right. I did originally need those tables when I had some different `WHERE`s but I took those `WHERE`s out. I've updated my question to show this simpler query. Unfortunately, the `GROUP BY` problem is still the same.

Comment: Did you take away `1` from the WHERE clause deliberately or by accident? I think you might want to either restore it or remove the subsequent `AND` as well.

Answer (score 0):

is depends heavily on your database setup

i suggest doing EXPLAIN on that query and analyze the output

you can step by step remove all joins that perform fast enough and concentrate on those that dont - it's easier to see what has to be indexed that way

aim to have less than 10000 rows scanned on every join

Edit: regarding your explain results - what is type of tc.code column? you used integers in condition:

```
AND tc.code IN (0, 20, 40)
```

and if tc.code is varchar then index usage is messed up

Comment: The most rows I have on any `JOIN` is 704. Is it really possible that the problem with my query is that one or more of the `JOIN`s is slow, knowing that without the `GROUP BY`, the query runs in 0.15 seconds?

Comment: analyzing EXPLAIN output also gives you information about which indexes are used. grouping does use indexes extensively and sometimes malformed condition will totally mess up ability of mysql to use indexes. you could try doing grou by on account_transaction table alone and then gradually add more and more joins to see how that affects performance. apparently there is bottleneck somewhere - just search for it :)

Comment: regarding your explain results - what is type of tc.code column? you used integers in condition:

AND tc.code IN (0, 20, 40)
and if tc.code is varchar then index usage is messed up

Comment: Well, it WAS a varchar but I changed it to an integer. However, that didn't noticeably improve performance.

Comment: Yes. (typing more characters here)

Comment: does it help dramatically if you just drop the tc.code condition? replace it with something comparable on higher level? like t.transaction_code_id IN (more than 3 values here)?

Comment: No. Even if I eliminate all the `WHERE`s completely it doesn't help much.